# Unable to suppress keys in a WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using one RichTextBox in C# Windows Application. I need to restrict the user from entering any key from keyboard at certain conditions. so, I wrote the following line of code in the `KeyDown` event of the `RichTextBox`:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

This is working fine for English US keyboard. But when I changed my regional settings to Korea and keyboard language to Korean, I can enter the Korean characters (like ?????) even after executing the above statement.

even i have tried with the following code

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

but in vain.

How can I suppress input with all keyboard layouts?

Comment: What happens when you set the control's ImeMode property to Off?

Comment: Have you tried the Key Up event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796654/how-can-i-prevent-the-keydown-event-of-a-form-in-c-sharp-from-firing-more-than-o

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to actually suppress keys, or do you want to prevent the user from editing the text?

Editing the text can easily be prevented with `richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;`

Your code probably doesn't work because input via IMEs doesn't count as key press.

Yet another alternative is trying to block in the `WM_CHAR`/`KeyPress` handler.

Comment: I need to supress the keys. The actualy theme is i should restrict the user from entering text at some of the index positions of the text inside the textbox.

Comment: @sampathkumar I'd use `ReadOnly` for that, and change it whenever the cursorpos or selection changes. One problematic case is when the selection spans the forbidden indices. You might also want to look into the existing `MaskedTextBox` control.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As you said, i tried with setting Readonly property to true at selected conditions and again making the Readonly property to false in keyup event. It meets the requirement. Thanks a lot.